# How to use ListView and TextBox objects in another method in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, methods, textbox

I have 3 ListViews and 3 TextBoxes in my project. How can I combine each other to work with a common method in WinForms C#?

Here is my example;

```
    // My common method.
    public void checkBarcode(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_ProductName, System.Windows.Forms.ListView lst_Products)
    {
        //do some things

        // At the end, i want to clear textbox and listbox of which product's button call this method
        txt_ProductName.Clear();
        lst_Products.Clear();
    }
    

    // My form members.
    // How can i send textbox and listview objects below to my checkBarcode method?
    private void btn_CheckEggBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBarcode(txt_Egg, lst_Products);
    }

    private void btn_CheckMilkBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBarcode(txt_Milk, lst_Milk);
    }

    private void btn_CheckChocloteBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBarcode(txt_Choclote, lst_Choclote);
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems to already work, could you explain a bit further what's not working?

Comment: I have checked and you are completely right at the moment and it works for me too. But I couldn't overcome of it those days. Maybe I made some mistakes in coding. Thanks to warn me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Tag` property

```
private void Init()
{
    btn_CheckEgg.Tag = new Tuple<TextBox, ListView>(txt_Egg, lst_Products);
    btn_CheckMilk.Tag = new Tuple<TextBox, ListView>(txt_Milk, lst_Milk);
    btn_CheckChoclote.Tag = new Tuple<TextBox, ListView>(txt_Choclote, lst_Choclote);
}

private void checkBarcode(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt_ProductName, System.Windows.Forms.ListView lst_Products)
{
    // do some things

    // At the end, I want to clear textbox and listbox of which product's 
    // button call this method
    txt_ProductName.Clear();
    lst_Products.Clear();
 }

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var tuple = (Tuple<TextBox, ListView>)btn.Tag;

    checkBarcode(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try tag prooerty in my project too as you use. Btw my codes were fiine those day, but some reason , they didn't work for me same days ago. Maybe i made some mistakes in my codes but now both work fine. Thanks